# Error installing @nestjs-modules/mailer@1.8.1

Tags: node.js, nestjs, backend, nodemailer, web-development-server

I am currently developing a backend system using NestJS, and I am encountering a problem while trying to install the @nestjs-modules/mailer dependency. The error message I receive is as follows:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: fella-pay-api@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @nestjs/common@10.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@nestjs/common
npm ERR!   @nestjs/common@"^10.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @nestjs/common@"^7.0.9 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0" from @nestjs-modules/mailer@1.8.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@nestjs-modules/mailer
npm ERR!   @nestjs-modules/mailer@"^1.8.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /home/sareto/.npm/_logs/2023-07-01T08_59_33_183Z-eresolve-report.txt
```

I have made attempts to conduct research, but I haven't achieved the desired outcome.

Comment: that package doesn't supports nestjs v10 yet. See: https://github.com/nest-modules/mailer/issues/997

Answer (score 1):

This error is occurred because of conflicts between the version of the packages, try running the command

```js
npm install --legacy-peer-deps @nestjs-modules/mailer
```